# Javascript function with substrings

Tags: javascript

I attend a Javascript course and I have some exercises as homework. In one of them I have to create a Javascript function with the following role: when I press the button, the function should take the data from the first field of text and put it in the next 3 input fields (day, month and year).

I wrote the function, but it doesn't work. Can you tell me why? Thank you.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <input type="text" value="20/12/2015" />
    <button onclick="calendar()">Push the button</button><br/>
    <input type="text" placeholder="day" /><br />
    <input type="text" placeholder="month" /><br />
    <input type="text" placeholder="year" />    
    <script>
    
    function calendar() {
        var x = "20/12/2015";
        var day = x.substring(0, 2);
        var month = x.substring(3, 5);
        var year = x.substring(6);
        document.getElementsByTagName("input")[1].innerHTML = day;
        document.getElementsByTagName("input")[2].innerHTML = month;
        document.getElementsByTagName("input")[3].innerHTML = year;
    }
        
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't know why someone downvoted this question. I guess this is a  genuine doubt. At least he tried.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `value` property to set/get the value of an [`<input>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input).

```js
function calendar() {
    var x = "20/12/2015";
        day = x.substring(0, 2);
        month = x.substring(3, 5);
        year = x.substring(6),
        inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");

    inputs[1].value = day;
    inputs[2].value = month;
    inputs[3].value = year;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="20/12/2015" />
<button onclick="calendar()">Push the button</button><br/>
<input type="text" placeholder="day" /><br />
<input type="text" placeholder="month" /><br />
<input type="text" placeholder="year" />
```

Answer (score 0):

To set an `input` element's value, you have to assign to its `value`. This is also true for `textarea` elements.

Assign to `innerHTML` when dealing with *pretty much any other kind of element*, but not for *input*s.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <input type="text" value="20/12/2015" />
    <button onclick="calendar()">Push the button</button><br/>
    <input type="text" placeholder="day" /><br />
    <input type="text" placeholder="month" /><br />
    <input type="text" placeholder="year" />    
    <script>
    
    function calendar() {
        var x = "20/12/2015";
        var day = x.substring(0, 2);
        var month = x.substring(3, 5);
        var year = x.substring(6);
        document.getElementsByTagName("input")[1].value = day;
        document.getElementsByTagName("input")[2].value = month;
        document.getElementsByTagName("input")[3].value = year;
    }
        
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```